# Making A discord channel private discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Could someone provide a code which makes a existing normal text channel into a private channel?

I want the code to be made by module discord.py

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a sample of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example code snippet on the discord.py docs

```py
overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
overwrite.send_messages = False
overwrite.read_messages = True
await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=overwrite)
```

Read through the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=permissions#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions) for more information

Hope this helps :D